# linux command line text file manipulation

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep

Let's say I have a text file with the following contents:

```
test
blablabla
test1
moreblabla
atest
blabla3
just*a*test
blabla14
test88
lastblabla
```

I want to delete **ONLY** the line that matches EXACTLY the string "test" and the line after it WITHOUT deleting the lines that contain the string "test"
So in my case I want to delete just the first and second lines but not the rest.

The above file is just an example, the contents of the file varies just like the string.

All the examples I found with `sed` only deal with deleting lines that just contain some string. I want to delete only the line that **IS** exactly that string.

Answer (score 4):

Just add `^` and `$` around the `test` regex to anchor your match.

```
sed -e '/^test$/,+1d' path/to/file
```

Or you could do `^ *test *$` for a line containing 'test' possibly with spaces.

Comment: The lines in the text file are made up only from letters and numbers, no spaces, no tabs or any other kind of characters.

If I read the string as a parameter from the command line should the script look like this:

`sed -e '/^"$1"$/,+1d' path/to/file`

Comment: That's nice. Well, you have my answer in either case.

Comment: It was a question :-)

Comment: Ah, you must have edited the first comment after I saw it; I didn't see the question. You need to learn about string substitution in bash, I think. Substitution doesn't occur within single quotes, only double quotes. And you may need to escape the dollar sign if your shell interprets it. But that is a separate question.

Comment: Why are you using `-e`

Comment: @vp_arth No it really isn't.

Comment: @User112638726, yes I mixed it with `-r`, sorry :)

Comment: Tested today and the correct script is: `sed -i -e "/^$1$/,+1d" path/to/the/file` Thank you @mathematical.coffee and all others who helped.